# How to load local html file content in an index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My team is developing a web app. I have an index.html file with a navigation menu scaffold on the left side and a content div on the right. I intend to load content from other local html files (in the same folder as the index) into the content div within the index. The navigation menu contains various buttons that loads up the specified content into the index. (Ex. user clicks profile account, so the profile account page is loaded into the content div within the index.)

My question is what is the best method to load content from local html files into the index?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more information, what technologies do You use? Is that pure HTML with javascript? Or do You have some server side?

Answer (score -1):

Dont use frame which might be tempting but in 2015 that's a big no no!!!
So, use Ajax to get the content in the right side when a user click on the link the left side